# Develop Google Analytics Reporting API v4 Error: JsonParseException: Unexpected character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 130))

Tags: google-analytics-api

I try to develop [Hello Analytics Reporting API v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-java) .I follow document step, I got some error : com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 130)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: (FileInputStream); line: 1, column: 3]

HelloAnalyticsReporting sample code:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.AnalyticsReportingScopes;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.AnalyticsReporting;

import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.ColumnHeader;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.DateRange;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.DateRangeValues;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.GetReportsRequest;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.GetReportsResponse;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.Metric;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.Dimension;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.MetricHeaderEntry;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.Report;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.ReportRequest;
import com.google.api.services.analyticsreporting.v4.model.ReportRow;

public class HelloAnalyticsReporting {
  private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Hello Analytics Reporting";
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
  private static final String KEY_FILE_LOCATION = "C:/Users/V002561/Downloads/charged-ridge-232301-a65076c6783a.p12";
  private static final String VIEW_ID = "XXXXXXX";
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      AnalyticsReporting service = initializeAnalyticsReporting();

      GetReportsResponse response = getReport(service);
      printResponse(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Initializes an Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
   *
   * @return An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
   * @throws IOException
   * @throws GeneralSecurityException
   */
  private static AnalyticsReporting initializeAnalyticsReporting() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {

    HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential
        .fromStream(new FileInputStream(KEY_FILE_LOCATION))
        .createScoped(AnalyticsReportingScopes.all());

    // Construct the Analytics Reporting service object.
    return new AnalyticsReporting.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();
  }

  /**
   * Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.
   *
   * @param service An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
   * @return GetReportResponse The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
   * @throws IOException
   */
  private static GetReportsResponse getReport(AnalyticsReporting service) throws IOException {
    // Create the DateRange object.
    DateRange dateRange = new DateRange();
    dateRange.setStartDate("7DaysAgo");
    dateRange.setEndDate("today");

    // Create the Metrics object.
    Metric sessions = new Metric()
        .setExpression("ga:sessions")
        .setAlias("sessions");

    Dimension pageTitle = new Dimension().setName("ga:pageTitle");

    // Create the ReportRequest object.
    ReportRequest request = new ReportRequest()
        .setViewId(VIEW_ID)
        .setDateRanges(Arrays.asList(dateRange))
        .setMetrics(Arrays.asList(sessions))
        .setDimensions(Arrays.asList(pageTitle));

    ArrayList<ReportRequest> requests = new ArrayList<ReportRequest>();
    requests.add(request);

    // Create the GetReportsRequest object.
    GetReportsRequest getReport = new GetReportsRequest()
        .setReportRequests(requests);

    // Call the batchGet method.
    GetReportsResponse response = service.reports().batchGet(getReport).execute();

    // Return the response.
    return response;
  }

  /**
   * Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
   *
   * @param response An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
   */
  private static void printResponse(GetReportsResponse response) {

    for (Report report: response.getReports()) {
      ColumnHeader header = report.getColumnHeader();
      List<String> dimensionHeaders = header.getDimensions();
      List<MetricHeaderEntry> metricHeaders = header.getMetricHeader().getMetricHeaderEntries();
      List<ReportRow> rows = report.getData().getRows();

      if (rows == null) {
         System.out.println("No data found for " + VIEW_ID);
         return;
      }

      for (ReportRow row: rows) {
        List<String> dimensions = row.getDimensions();
        List<DateRangeValues> metrics = row.getMetrics();

        for (int i = 0; i < dimensionHeaders.size() && i < dimensions.size(); i++) {
          System.out.println(dimensionHeaders.get(i) + ": " + dimensions.get(i));
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < metrics.size(); j++) {
          System.out.print("Date Range (" + j + "): ");
          DateRangeValues values = metrics.get(j);
          for (int k = 0; k < values.getValues().size() && k < metricHeaders.size(); k++) {
            System.out.println(metricHeaders.get(k).getName() + ": " + values.getValues().get(k));
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Error log :

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 130)): Expected space separating root-level values
 at [Source: (FileInputStream); line: 1, column: 3]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:669)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:567)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportMissingRootWS(ParserMinimalBase.java:614)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._verifyRootSpace(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1629)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._parsePosNumber(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:1369)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:824)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:723)
    at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonParser.nextToken(JacksonParser.java:55)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.startParsing(JsonParser.java:221)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:380)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:355)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:87)
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.fromStream(GoogleCredential.java:250)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.fromStream(GoogleCredential.java:226)
    at HelloAnalyticsReporting.initializeAnalyticsReporting(HelloAnalyticsReporting.java:56)
    at HelloAnalyticsReporting.main(HelloAnalyticsReporting.java:36)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the json parser. It looks like you are passing it a P12 key file instead of a json file. I'm guessing, when creating the credentials you selected P12 instead of JSON, see [create credentials](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-java#create_credentials) in the documentation.

I think you can still use the p12 file by changing the code that loads the key to:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new FileInputStream(KEY_FILE_LOCATION))
    .build()
    .createScoped(AnalyticsReportingScopes.all());
```

I haven't tried this myself so it could be wrong, see the [javadocs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleCredential) on GoogleCredential. The easiest thing may just be to recreate the credentials and get a json file instead.

I hope this helps and good luck.